# Spring tests with @ContextConfiguration and SpringJUnit4ClassRunner in Eclipse 4.3 seem slow

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, junit

I have a suite of 54 tests (a handful of which are properly integration that write some data to a mysql database and delete it).  It takes 117 seconds to run my junit tests with the eclipse test runner.  I have another app with 244 tests in a similar mix that work with couch and these take 308 seconds.

A VS 2010 c# project with a similar mix of ~50 similar tests (using spring.net) runs in  ~10 seconds.

I also have a mocha node test suite with 260 tests (similar mix to the above) that takes 2 seconds to run.

My understanding is that the application contexts loaded by ContextConfiguration are cached, so that shouldn't be an issue.  I'm finding myself increasingly frustrated by the length of time it takes to run my java application tests.

I guess I'm wondering whether 2 seconds per test is about what I should be expecting. Whether anything can be done to speed things up.

Finally, if one can only hope to get some incremental improvements with junit and eclipse, I'm wondering how folks can stand it.

Comment: Does each test initialize a context?

Comment: No, they are cached as far as I can tell from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't use `@DirtiesContext`, this will cause context reloading per class or test.
Also `<beans default-lazy-init="true">` in your test context may help by initializing only the beans needed on the current test

Comment: Time went down to 116 seconds. I do notice that the tests that touch the database are the slowest. 3 tests against a org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository that hits the database and calls deleteAll() after each test take 15 seconds to run.  It's hitting a mysql database on a vm hosted on my development machine.  It just seems really slow.

Comment: That is really too much! That would make sense if you were doing some batch inserts/updates, or running slow queries. Probably there is something with your connection to db...hmm I can only speculate. I have a project with 10 integration tests which all do CRUD operations on 3 tables and they all finish for around 3/4 seconds.